# OpenGL Trying to render a cube but there are weird lines between planes

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, coordinate-transformation

Cube rendering
[image]

Hey, i think there may be a mistake in either how i'm sending the data to the vertex or the way my indices are ordered with GL_CCW

```
struct Vertex
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 color;
    glm::vec3 normal;
};
```

Vertices using Vertex struct

```
Vertex vertices[] =
{   
/*FRONT SQUARE*/
    ///BOTTOM LEFT
glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.f), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),

    ///bottom RIGHT
    glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),
    ////TOP RIGHT
    glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),
    ///TOP LEFT
    glm::vec3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),

    ///BOTTOM LEFT
    glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -1.f), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),

    ///bottom RIGHT
    glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),
    ////TOP RIGHT
    glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),
    ///TOP LEFT
    glm::vec3(-0.5f, 0.5f, -1.0f), glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f)

};

unsigned noOfVertices = sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(Vertex);
```

This is my indices ordering

```
GLuint indices[] =
{
    // /front face

    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,

    // right
    1, 5, 6,
    6, 2, 1,
    // back
    7, 6, 5,
    5, 4, 7,
    // left
    4, 0, 3,
    3, 7, 4,
    // bottom
    4, 5, 1,
    1, 0, 4,
    // top
    3, 2, 6,
    6, 7, 3


};

unsigned noOfIndices = sizeof(indices) / sizeof(GLuint);
```

Main function and initliase the window

```
  int main()
    {
```

Initiase window

```
    ///initialise GLFW for Window
    if (glfwInit() == GLFW_FALSE)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::GLFW-INTI::FAILED" << "\n";
        glfwTerminate();
    }

    ///Create window with functions
    GLFWwindow* window;
    const int window_height = 480;
    int window_width = 680;
    int framebuffer_height = window_height;
    int framebuffer_width = window_width;
    char* title = "mytutorial";

    int GLverMAJ = 3;
    int GLverMin = 3;

    ///sets how  the window should be drawn and which hints
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, GLverMAJ);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, GLverMin);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);

    ///create the window with the previously set options
    window = glfwCreateWindow(window_width, window_height, title, NULL, NULL);

    //checks if window created
    if (window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR:::GLFWCREATEWINDOWFAILED" << "\n";
    }

    ///sets the frame buffer size
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &framebuffer_width, &framebuffer_height);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //need to read on this part
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    //initiliase the glew
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::GLEWINIT::FAILED" << "\n";
    }
```

initiliase opengl options

```
///enable functions first
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

        //initialise the enabled  functions
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

        ///set the way its draw
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW);

        ///set the polygon mode and fill ////Set as GL_LINE TO LOOK AT CUBE MESH
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

This is where i initialise the matrices the view, project and model
        ///initialise the matrices

```
    ///view
    ///front, position, up then use in lookat
    glm::vec3 cameraPos(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glm::vec3 cameraUp(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    glm::vec3 cameraFront(0.f, 0.f, -0.1f);

    glm::mat4 ViewMatrix(1.f);
    ViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraFront, cameraUp);

    ///set up prespective projection

    float fov = 90.f;
    float nearPlane = -1.f;
    float farPlane = 1000.f;

    ///projection
    glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix(1.f);
    ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), static_cast<float>(framebuffer_width / framebuffer_height), nearPlane, farPlane);


    //Model Matrix
    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix(1.f);
```

Then i create my shaders

```
    ///set up SHADERS
    char infolog[512];
    GLint success;

    GLuint Vertexshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    ///std::string str_src = 

    std::string temp = "";
    std::string src = "";
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open("vert.glsl");
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline(infile, temp))
            src += temp + "\n";

    }
    infile.close();

    const GLchar* source = src.c_str();

    ///link created shader with shader source
    glShaderSource(Vertexshader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(Vertexshader);

    ///error check compilation status
    glGetShaderiv(Vertexshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(Vertexshader, 512, NULL, infolog);
        std::cout << infolog;
    }



    success = 0;

    GLuint FragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    ///std::string str_src = 

    temp = "";
    src = "";
    infile.open("frag.glsl");
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline(infile, temp))
            src += temp + "\n";

    }
    infile.close();

    source = src.c_str();

    ///link created shader with shader source
    glShaderSource(FragmentShader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShader);

    ///error check compilation status
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShader, 512, NULL, infolog);
        std::cout << infolog;
    }
```

Link the created shaders with the program

```
     ///create and link the program
    success = 0;
    GLuint programID;

    programID = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(programID, Vertexshader);
    glAttachShader(programID, FragmentShader);

    glLinkProgram(programID);

    glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programID, 512, NULL, infolog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::COULD_NOT_LINK_PROGRAM" << "\n";
        std::cout << infolog << "\n";

    }
```

after linking unuse and delete buffers

```
///after linking we unuse the program and delete the shaders
    glUseProgram(0);
    glDeleteShader(Vertexshader);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShader);
```

This is where i initiliase VAO VBO AND EBO

```
///vbo, ebo and vertex array
    GLuint VAO;
    GLuint VBO;
    GLuint EBO;

    //gen and bind vao
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);


    ///gen vbo
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, noOfVertices * sizeof(Vertex), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    ///gen EBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, noOfIndices * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

This is the part where i feel like there may be a problem

```
    ///tell  buffer where data is located
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //colour
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, color));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    ///use program send in uniforms to the shader.
    glUseProgram(programID);

    ///GLuint s = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ViewMatrix");
    GLuint s = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ModelMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(s, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ModelMatrix));

    s = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ProjectionMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(s, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ProjectionMatrix));

    s = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ViewMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(s, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ViewMatrix));

    glUseProgram(0);
    ///main while loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        //clear
        glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        ///draw
        glfwPollEvents();



        glUseProgram(programID);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);


        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, noOfIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        ///flush

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glFlush();


    ///unuse

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the near plane and the far plane have to be positive values for [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00665.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787) and `static_cast<float>(framebuffer_width / framebuffer_height)` would be an integral division:

```cpp
float fov = 90.f;
float nearPlane = 0.1f; // 0.1 instead of -1.0
float farPlane = 1000.f;

glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix(1.f);
ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), 
    static_cast<float>(framebuffer_width) / static_cast<float>(framebuffer_height),
    nearPlane, farPlane);
```

See [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00665.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787):

> ```
> GLM_FUNC_DECL mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> glm::perspective(
>       T     fovy,
>       T     aspect,
>       T     near,
>       T     far 
>   )
> ```
>
> [...]
>   `near`    Specifies the distance from the viewer to the near clipping plane (always positive).
>   `far`   Specifies the distance from the viewer to the far clipping plane (always positive).

---

The *glm* library provides matrix operations related to OpenGL and GLSL. The [glm API documentation](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/index.html) refers to [The OpenGL Shading Language specification 4.20](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.20.pdf).

See [The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6, 5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors, page 101](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf):

> To initialize a matrix by specifying vectors or scalars, the components are assigned to the matrix elements in column-major order.
>
> ```
> mat4(float, float, float, float,  // first column
>        float, float, float, float,  // second column
>        float, float, float, float,  // third column
>        float, float, float, float); // fourth column
> ```

This means the transformation of the vertex coordinate in the vertex shader has to be:

```c
gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(vertex_position,1.0);
```

See also [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations):

Likely the matrix can be transposed when set to the uniform, by setting the 3rd paramter of [`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) to `GL_TRUE`:

```cpp
GLuint s = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ModelMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(s, 1, GL_TRUE, glm::value_ptr(ModelMatrix));

s = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ProjectionMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(s, 1, GL_TRUE, glm::value_ptr(ProjectionMatrix));

s = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "ViewMatrix");
glUniformMatrix4fv(s, 1, GL_TRUE, glm::value_ptr(ViewMatrix));
```

And compute the vertex coordinate transformation in the reverse order:

```c
gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position,1.0) * ModelMatrix * ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix;
```

---

Further, the winding order of the faces of the cube a is clockwise, so it has to be:

<s>`glFrontFace(GL_CCW);`</s>
`glFrontFace(GL_CW);`

---

Change the camera position to

```
glm::vec3 cameraPos(0.f, 0.f, 2.f);
```

and you'll get the following result:

[image]

Comment: I think i may have the order of my matrix multipcation wrong because i added all those changes but instead of displaying what you have. It displayed it closer to the screen. Mind taking a look?        gl_Position =   vec4(vertex_position,1.0) * ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix ;

Comment: @Darman It has to be `gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(vertex_position,1.0);`

Answer (score 0):

To me, it would seem that your program is working correctly. If I'm not mistaken, then your camera is located inside the cube, looking straight from the position of one of the faces at the face on the other side. What you're seeing is exactly what one would expect to see in this case. In the center of the image you have the two triangles that make the backside of the face you're looking out of. The "weird lines" you get are simply the edges of the triangles that make the other faces. Since your camera is inside the cube, these faces necessarily reach all the way behind your camera and everything gets cut off at the near plane, which is where you get the outer rectangle from that "encloses" everything.

Everything is a bit squashed because this

```
static_cast<float>(framebuffer_width / framebuffer_height)
```

will not have the effect you most likely intend it to have. You are still performing an integer division here.

Also, I'm not sure what exactly you expect the effect of using a negative value for the near plane to be. Most likely, it's also not what you actually want, I suggest you use some positive value, e.g., `0.1f` there…

Comment: The camera is not inside the cube, because the camera position is `glm::vec3 cameraPos(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);`, which is used for `glm::lookAt`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Indeed, I initially misread the coordinates to be (0,0,0). I updated my answer accordingly. However, if I didn't still overlook something, then the camera is located at (0, 0, 1), which is the center of the backside of the cube and is looking at the origin, which should mean that it's looking into the cube. That would also be consistent with what we see on the screen, particularly the side faces being cut off at the near clipping plane…

Comment: The major issue is `float nearPlane = -1.f;`. That is an undefined behaviour and makes mathematically not any sense.

Comment: Is that effecting the calculation, i added the changes suggested and it ended up pushing it towards the screen if that makes sense. I think it could be my matrix multiplication                                                                                                                            gl_Position =   vec4(vertex_position,1.0) * ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix ;                                                                                                                                also about the static casting i thought that was for the aspect ratio of the window